# plotly subplots: is it possible to have one subplots occupy multiple columns or rows

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to have 3 plots on one figure using plotly subplots.
Naturally, I could do just 3 rows but I am trying to have first two figures side-by-side and another being stretched out. Overall I am trying to get a layout on the picture (that I made with paint):
[image]
Is it possible and if yes how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Refer to the references for [examples](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#custom-sized-subplot-with-subplot-titles) of your desired features.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using `make_subplots` arguments: `column_widths` and `row_heights` but neither do help as in this cases of 2x2 grid they will affect top part, the one I am not trying to modify

Comment: oh, found it! There is an option "colspan" in `specs`! `specs=[[{}, {}],[{"colspan": 2}, None]]` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation examples](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#custom-sized-subplot-with-subplot-titles), using specs to define multi col span:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{}, {}],
           [{"colspan": 2}, None]],
    subplot_titles=("First Subplot","Second Subplot", "Third Subplot"))
```